# How can I show/hide more than 2 span classes and toggle between them in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle between more than 2 span classes and initially it displays only one class. Is it possible to do it with the help of Jquery. If not, any other way to solve my problem.

Sample HTML code

```
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
```

Sample Jquery code

```
$('.symbol span').toggle();
```

This code works fine.

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc182sxx/)

But what I want is

```
<li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span>
<span class="hinoff">a</span><span class="hinon">b</span></li>
```

and some Jquery code to toggle between these 4 span classes and initially displaying only one.

It means initially it displays any of the span class, let's say *span class = "off"* and it is showing *'`'*. Now I want to toggle to my class on clicking on my element to let's say *span class = "hinoff"* and it should show *'a'*.

Comment: what something to toggle between ?? Your question is not clear..
what are you trying to achieve in simple and clear words

Comment: something means some code to toggle between these 4 classes

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: Did you understood what I am trying to do here. Yeah I can make fiddle of my problem but that won't help if you didn't understood what I am trying to do.

Comment: What does "some code to toggle between these 4 classes" mean?  What is the expected result?  You still haven't explained that to us.

Comment: A fiddle WILL help people to understand. Why the attitude when you are asking for help?

Comment: Okay I am adding the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling this function should show the next `span` and hide the others no matter how many `span`s there are.

```
function showNext() {
    var $shownElement = $('.symbol span:visible').first();
    var $elementToShow = $shownElement.next();
    console.log($elementToShow);
    if (!$elementToShow.length) $elementToShow = $('.symbol span').first();
    var $shownElement = $('.symbol span:visible');
    $('.symbol span').hide();
    $elementToShow.show();
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vq6dspq/)

Comment: I believe you should use:

`if (!$elementToShow.length) elementToShow = $shownElement.first();`

Your `if` will be always true otherwise (just tested similar solution in jsfidle)

Comment: @Drecker Thanks. I just tested too and noticed that. It's fixed now.

Comment: I want to toggle between classes. I have two data sets for that I would toggle between 2 classes for each data set. But your function will make the next span class visible each time it is called. Any way I could toggle between the span classes.

Comment: @DeveloperVidit Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t39o6e4d/

Answer (score 2):

To show selected span and hide all others, just hide them all and show the one you want:

```
$('.symbols span').hide();
$('.symbols span.' + selectedClass).show();
```

Comment: @DeveloperVidit - AlliterativeAlice added one fiddle showing exactly this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816891/how-can-i-show-hide-more-than-2-span-classes-and-toggle-between-them-in-jquery/25817305#comment40388102_25817067